# Xcode Build post-actions from script file

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, build

I have a project with two targets and I want to add Build post-action for both targets. But I don't want to copy my script, because it may be very long, or maybe I want to change it in future, anyway, I want to have one script in separate file. When I use path to script instead script, for example:

```
./Common/Scripts/name_of_script.sh
```

Screenshot of my post-action:

[image]

It hasn't been run, but if I replace it with script, it works. How I can do it? Why post-actions don't work like Build Phases?

Comment: Are you using $(PROJECT_DIR)/Common/Scripts/name_of_script.sh for the path?

Comment: @RamonPoca yes, I tried to use `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Common/Scripts/name_of_script.sh` and `./Common/Scripts/name_of_script.sh` paths

Comment: Have you checked the script is executable, i.e. chmod +x name_of_script.sh ?

Comment: You can also add a manual script with: `echo "$(PROJECT_DIR)"; ls -l "$(PROJECT_DIR)/Common/Scripts/name_of_script.sh"` and check in the build output the path is right and the mode has the executable flag(s) (rwxr-xr-x)

Comment: @RamonPoca I can run this script from Console, and it works. But after Xcode Build I don't see same result.

Comment: Append the console output of the "run script" phase of the build.

Comment: @RamonPoca There is nothing in Console related to my script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133282/discussion-between-ramon-poca-and-artem-novichkov).